# How do I move all Kafka topics to working brokers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a development environment with one Zookeeper and one Kafka broker on AWS.

I created a topic (`foo`) on a broker (`1001`) that is now destroyed. As a result, the leader for this topic is not available:

```
$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper ec2-99-999-999-999.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181 --topic foo
Topic:foo   PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: foo  Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
    Topic: foo  Partition: 1    Leader: -1  Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

However, I have another broker available:

```
$ ~/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh ec2-88-888-888-888.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181 ls /brokers/ids
Connecting to ec2-88-888-888-888.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[1002]
```

I have two questions:

- How do I make this new broker (`1002`) the leader for my topic (`foo`)?
- How can I make this happen automatically in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool to move that topic to broker `1002`.

The [Custom partition assignment and migration](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_partitionassignment) section in the documentation details that process:

1) Create a custom reassignment JSON file, for example:

```
{"version":1,"partitions":[
    {"topic":"foo","partition":0,"replicas":[1002]},
    {"topic":"foo","partition":1,"replicas":[1002]},
    // for each partition
]}
```

2) Submit that jobb to the reassignment tool:

```
bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --reassignment-json-file custom-reassignment.json --execute
```

3) Monitor the progress with the `--verify` flag:

```
bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --reassignment-json-file custom-reassignment.json --verify
```

Comment: It says `Reassignment of partition foo-0 failed`

Comment: Ideally you want to reassign partitions before decommissioning brokers. If that broker is gone for good (and its data now lost), you may have to destroy the topic by hand (with `rmr /brokers/topics/<topic_name>` in zkshell) and recreate a new one.